# (re)plumbing trap for double basin sink

Tags: plumbing, repair, kitchen-sink

One of the p-traps under my sink was corroded and leaking. When I looked into replacing it, I saw that it was recommended to just have the garbage disposal and non disposal side of the sink come together into one trap. I was thinking I should instal new elbows on the disposal and non-disposal sides, and a t above the p-trap.

Am I better off just buying all new fittings or can I reuse the chrome p-trap? should I replace the chrome fittings with PVC? Is there perhaps a kit I can just buy that will have all these fittings?

Should I cap one half of the y coming out of the wall, or replace it entirely? Should I cap it with a cleaner cap? It seems to be glued into the waste stack and I don't want to do too much.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to have the trap directly below the tail piece from the basin that does not have the disposal.

You would cap or eliminate the Y fitting so you just have one outlet.

The disposal will connect straight over to the tail piece into a Tee ( baffled tee ) fitting attached to the tail piece and the tee will go straight down into the trap.

Here is a basic [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QG0L6dHmMsQ).

[How do you drain a garbage disposal?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/31079/how-do-you-drain-a-garbage-disposal)

Comment: Yup, and it looks to me like you will need to cut the tailpiece back significantly, and use the currently unused part of the wye... good time to think about going with plastic for everything.

Comment: Can I just use a basic cap for the y fitting, or does it need something special?

Comment: The unused part of the y is very close to the tail piece, about 4 inches. Prior it had another elbow coming out to make the connection possible. It seems like having the trap in between the two would be easier in the space down there.

Comment: All true but as it is noted the "straight over" should be sloped. However, the OP's original install isn't "bad" - just uncommon. They could just replace the ptrap that is bad and be done with it.